# Disable nouveau before installation

Tags: installation, gpu, optimus

I'm trying to install Antergos in a laptop with an optimus card. However, it freezes when I have to choose a desktop flavor. Searching on the net I found [here](https://forum.antergos.com/topic/5367/cnchi-freezes-on-desktop-environment-select/4) that the problem lies in the gpu. There's a really complete guide [here](https://antergos.com/wiki/hardware/graphics/bumblebee-for-nvidia-optimus/) about this topic, anyhow, I don't really know how to disable nouveau before the liveCd starts.

Comment: Just explain what you found with conclusion of how it may help you then ask about what is not clear for you, SuperUser cannot read the guide for you

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, to be able to install Antergos with an optimus card you'll need to disable nouvea and install bumblebee. The [guide](https://antergos.com/wiki/hardware/graphics/bumblebee-for-nvidia-optimus/)
you shared is a really good one, I did install Antergos with an optimus card following it. By your question I deduce you don't know how to pass kernel parameters.

> how to disable nouveau before the liveCd starts

Let's take a look at [arch's kernel parameters wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/kernel_parameters).

> There are three ways to pass options to the kernel and thus control its behaviour:
>
> 1. When building the kernel. See Kernel Compilation for details.
> 2. When starting the kernel (usually, when invoked from a boot loader).
> 3. At runtime (through the files in /proc and /sys). See sysctl for
>    details.

In your case you'll have to pass the option when building the kernel:

> Syslinux
>
> Press Tab when the menu shows up and add them at the end of the string:

Ergo when booting go to `Start Antergos Live` option (note that this may change and show other optionsas as: x86_64, x86_64 nvidia fallback, etc.) and pulse Tab an add `modprobe.blacklist=nouveau` at the end of the string. You'd be able to finish a normal installation.

Then just after start your first session delete nouveau drivers: `sudo pacman -Rc xf86-video-nouveau` and follow the guide in the next steps.

The comings steps are:

> Fully upgrade the system
>
> Install Bumblebee (you'd choose your drivers according to your hardware)
>
> Add yourself to bumblebee group
>
> Enable bumblebeed service

Hope this may help you!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SuperUser.  Would you be able to edit this post, and improve your answer?  Possibly by going more in-depth on how to achieve the results the asker wants?